# SQL Server 2019 Backups Suddenly Slow Most of the Time

Tags: sql-server

We running 2 small databases on SQL Server Express 2019 CU15 (on Windows Server 2019), and backups have randomly become very slow most of the time over the last 3 months

Databases are 4GB and 8GB, so they used to take about 1 minute and 8 minutes to backup. But without apparent reason, they now take 15 and 30 minutes to backup. In itself, these delays are not extreme, it's just that I feel something is abnormal and am afraid the problem might increase over time.

Out of an average week, we will notice 1-2 standard speed backups, and 5-6 very slow ones. Backups are always running at the same time, daily.

If I run manual backups, they are usually very slow.
I also tried attaching completely non-related DB to this instance, and backup was also slow (so it's not DB-related)

The read operation seem fine (BACKUP DATABASE xyz TO DISK = 'NUL:' WITH COPY_ONLY; runs very fast)

I noticed ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION having very long wait_time while performing the backups, but not sure what to do with this information

Since backups are sometimes fast, I somehow discarded the hardware, disk, DB and SQL-config issues.
And I'm leaning towards some other concurrent process being involved

But I'm running out of ideas to troubleshoot this, so I'm fishing for any input that might help me move forward !

**Edit 1:**
Thanks Aaron and J.D. for your ideas

The thing that is bugging me is that throughout the day, we mostly get very slow backups. So I'd assume that if another process was slowing down the thing (other backup job, defrag, A-V, ...) , it wouldn't run all day and I would see some activity on the disks on the Perf Monitor. But even though everything is quiet in the perf monitor, if I manually start a backup job, 9/10 times I'll get very slow backup

I ran CrystalDiskMark and am getting constant and good perf on disks. Other processes are also showing good disk perf

Whatever I test, it seems only SQL Server is slow to write to disk (and according to msdb..backupset, they have gotten slower and slower over the last 5 months)

I checked the sys.dm_exec_requests and no other processes seem to consume resources. But the BACKUP DATABASE one is stuck on **suspended** with **ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION** for lengthy periods

I feel like it might be a very specific issue with our configuration, but I've been battling with this issue for a few months now, so I'm starting to run out of ideas on how to progress

**Edit 2:**

Just to clear that out, I did try backing up on a different drive (sitting on a different disk) and I'm still getting slow backups with SQL Server (while having excellent performance on that drive with other tools).

So I'm definitely running out of ideas on where to look. Only option I see would be to reinstall SQL Server, but not too confident it would fix so I will live with this issue for now and hope it won't be getting too bad over time.

Comment: In addition to Aaron's excellent advice, I'd like to mention that hardware and disk issues can be intermittent too. Somewhat complimentary to what Aaron said, if you test the disk itself (taking SQL Server out of the equation) for a second, is it repeatedly showing the speeds it should be? You can use a tool like [CrystalDiskMark](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/) to test the disk directly.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not alone here.  Having the very same issues but with much larger databases.  7TB of databases used to backup in 3 hours.  Now, they generally take 4 to 5 and sometimes as much a 20.  I monitor the machine quite closely.... there's nothing else running on either the source machine or the backup destination.  And, it real slow stuff is totally unprictable.

Comment: @JeffModen in our case the issue somehow disappeared without taking any action or updating anything. Backups ran slow for a few months and then suddenly came back to normal. Never knew exactly what was the bottleneck, just weird stuff!

Comment: @lewou - Thanks for the feedback.  At this point, I certainly wouldn't mind such a miracle. :D